# currencymanager AddNew() method c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am trying to add new records to my database using currencymanager addnew method but it is not updating the database, here is the complete code.

```
namespace currencyManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt;
        CurrencyManager cm;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("data source=COUNTER16-PC,initial catalog=myDatabase;integrated security=true");
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Students", con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cm = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dt];
            txtID.DataBindings.Add("text",dt,"ID");
            txtFname.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "FirstName");
            txtLname.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "LASTNAME");
            txtState.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "STATE");
            txtPhone.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "PHONE");
            txtEmail.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "EMAIL");
            txtGrade.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "GRADEYEAR");
            txtGrade.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "GPA");
            txtProgram.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "PROGRAM");
            txtNews.DataBindings.Add("text", dt, "NEWLETTER");

        }

        private void btn_first_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.Position = 0;
        }

        private void btn_prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.Position--;
        }

        private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.Position++;
        }

        private void btn_last_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.Position = cm.Count - 1;
        }

        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.AddNew();
        }

        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.EndCurrentEdit();
        }

        private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cm.RemoveAt(cm.Position);
        }
    }
}
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the code of method `AddNew` ?

Comment: `i am trying to add new records to my database` There is no adding to database in the code you supplied. Stackoverflow charges a small fee to read minds

Comment: The `AddNew` will just update your underlying databound object, which is a `DataTable` in your example. It has nothing to do with the origin of the data. If you loaded the data by an SQL command, then maybe save it by another one.

Comment: after `cm.AddNew();` make sure your `datatable` contains new record then `update` your `adapter`